# Matlab plot multiple 3d lines

Tags: matlab, plot

I have `n` pairs of points :

```
(x1,y1,z1) (u1,v1,w1) ,  
(x2,y2,z2) (u2,v2,w2) ,
....                  , 
(xn,y2,zn) (un,vn,wn)
```

I want to plot 3d line for each pair.
All lines in the same window (plot).

So I will have in total `n` lines .

How can I do this in Matlab ?

Thanks

Comment: Depends how you have your data organized.  Two matrixes, several variables?

Comment: Do `plot3([x1 u1],[y1 v1],[z1 w1])` to plot one line. Then type `hold on` and plot another line. This is the basic concept.

Comment: I can have the points organized in any way

Comment: Suppose I have this two pairs : 
(0,0,0) (3,3,3)   and  (-1,-1,-1) (-5,-5,-5).  Can you please write the code to this two lines ?

Comment: I have given you the basic format.

Comment: Ok thnak you !
Worked :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parag's answer is of course correct. However, you can also plot multiple lines with one call to `plot3`, if data are arranged correctly. For your example:

```
x = [0 , 3; -1, -5]';
y = [0 , 3; -1, -5]';
z = [0 , 3; -1, -5]';

plot3(x, y, z)
```

Specifically, `plot3` (just as `plot` and `line`) produces one line for each column of its three (two) inputs.

Comment: Ok thnak you ! Worked :)